# Is it possible to query for media insights in a single query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Based on Facebook's documentation, the only way for me to obtain Instagram Insights on an Instagram posts is if I query for a single post. Is there a way for me to query for insights like impressions in a single query.

Right now, I'm just doing /id/media and taking each media id and doing /mediaId/insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works with a single query:

```
/id/media?fields=id,insights.metric(engagement,impressions,reach)
```

Comment: You're the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here, with the existing approach, you will be able to get an error while trying to retrieve `video_views`

```
/media?fields=media_type,timestamp,insights.metric(engagement,impressions,reach,saved,video_views)
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Can not show video views count for non video media",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "BEyxl0daG29"
  }
}
```